# How to Fill DockPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have this .xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="Eagle_Eye.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eagle_Eye"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="EE" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0" >
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  >
                <TextBlock Name="debugText" Height="20" Background="Azure" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>



        <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></WebBrowser>
        </DockPanel>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this .cs code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Eagle_Eye
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            debugText.Text = "hello";
            webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

What it gives me is this :

[image]

It just takes half of the screen, and there is scroll-bars. What am I missing ?

What I want is this :

[image]

*The yellow box should contain `TextBlock` and the blue box should contain `WebBrowser`, without scroll-bars, stretched. *

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here,
First, Dockpanel by default has the "LastChildFill" option, meaning the last child fills the rest of the panel, if you bind the last child to bottom it will not stretch..
Second, stackpanel items do not stretch, and always try to take minimal space.

So what I would do is replace:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser"></WebBrowser>
        </StackPanel>
```

With this:

```
            <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></WebBrowser>
```

Comment: Thanks for half solution

Comment: Can you help me out with the rest, please see the question, I have edited that

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the web browser component, I assume that the scrollbars appear as it's minimum size requirement is not met.
you can probably disable scrollbar visibility but the window will not look good.

or are you asking how to allow resizing the window? 
(these are controlled with NoResize=False, CanMinimize=True, CanResize=True on the window control)

Comment: After searching a lot, I found that can't be done. Well not impossible, but too broad for here. So I reduced the question.